# Why GAE application is missing in Google Developers Console?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api

One of my Google App Engine application somehow is missing in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project). I am sure it was there before.

Now If I click on the link from the Google App Engine / Application settings page, then it opens the page and returns the error `You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page`.

I am the only owner of GAE app and trying to access Google Developers Console under the same account.

How should I fix it?

Comment: That's bizarre. Did you accidently sign into another google account, like a different gmail or something?

Comment: @Gwell, I've tried to sign out and sign in again, so the correct account is used.

Comment: Very strange issue LA_. Are you using the new cloud console, or the older looking one? The new one : https://console.developers.google.com/project. The old one is: https://appengine.google.com/. In the new one when you select your project and go down to Billing on the left side, there should be a button that says Enable billing. The older console seems to just redirect you to the newer cloud console. Otherwise, I guess you will need to contact them to see what's going on.

Comment: @Gwell, the older console link I believe https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect (since you've given GAE console link instead). But I've tried both, the project is missing there (but present at GAE console). Not sure how to contact Google about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to contact Google support would be to go to their PIT. [This is the link](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list).  If there is a valid problem with your account, I believe they can contact you on there privately to get to the root of your issue.

As to your specific problem, I would try logging out of everything, trying a different browser, with both the [new console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and the [old one](http://appengine.google.com).

Comment: Thanks for the idea with PIT. I've tried to use another browser (and repeated it again just now) - it doesn't help.

Comment: Just adding to what Patrice said above.  This happens when you sign in to any google service (Gmail, Apps for Work, App Engine) using one account and then access any one of those services in the same browser at another time using a different account.  I've had to reset cookies, local storage, close the browser and clear everything to get rid of that error.  I have two Google accounts I use regularly, so I use Safari for one and Chrome for the other exclusively.

Comment: I've raised it as the issue, so Google Support is looking at the problem. Again, thanks for the idea.

Comment: It looks like Google no longer allow "old and free" Google App users to access to certain parts of Google Developer Console. For my case, I can access many other sections except **APIs & auth**. When I clicked on **Credentials**, it says _You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page_, but my previously set JavaScript Origin still working, just that I can no longer add new domains to it. Perhaps signing up for free trial can do the trick, but I haven't tried it out yet.

Comment: **UPDATE:** Signing up for free trial not solving the problem either. Still have no permission to access the **Credentials**

Comment: Can't access the credentials too

Answer (score 0):

have you tried accessing App Console with a Google Chrome incognito window ?

Check that billing configuration is OK or credit card not expired.

Regards
Paolo

Comment: Just tried to use Google Chrome incognito mode - the same problem. The billing is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem just now. It kept complaining "You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page" when I was accessing it on Chrome.

What I do is just switching to use Microsoft Edge with no Google account signed in. It works! I can now access the Credentials page again. =)

p/s: It's quite funny to have Google products work on Edge but not Chrome. =P

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a permission tab along with others(Overview,Api Auths) CLick on permission and in checkbox for your email as owner check it . It worked for me